# no such method error when trying to run spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app
 Here is the error i am getting :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider: method <init>()V not found
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:158)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:138)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:111)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:77)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:529)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:299)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
at com.ceb.tc.TcCacheApplication.main(TcCacheApplication.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
2017-08-17 07:49:35,202 [background-preinit] INFO  org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
```

I have tried changing the spring boot app version to 1.5.1 to 1.5.6 but it is of no use.  I am stuck now. So need help

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>admin-repository</id>
        <name>adminRepo</name>
        <url>file:${project.build.directory}\..\..\admin\mvnrepository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>b7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <!--  --><version>5.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the class that runs the application

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TcCacheApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TcCacheApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have corrected my pom.xml to accommodate the changes suggested, except for the log4j version most have been removed . I can't remove the version for log4j because it gives me an error that version number is required at the time of command "mvn clean install"

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>b7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>

            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
+- com.gartner.ceb:admin:jar:12.0.0:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime

|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.16:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.16:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compil
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.8.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0:compile
|     \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.16:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.16:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.16:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.9:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.9:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:tes
|  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
|  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
|  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
|  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
|  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
|  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
+- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.6:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
|     +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
|     +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
|     \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
+- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:3.6.1:compile
|  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:runtime
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
|  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:compile
+- net.sf.flexjson:flexjson:jar:2.1:compile
+- axis:axis:jar:1.2:compile
+- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
+- jdom:jdom:jar:b7:compile
+- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
+- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
|  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.10:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
+- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
\- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Please show the code of your class that contains the main method

Comment: @StimpsonCat Just added class code .

Comment: Stop mixing spring boot versions, remove the `1.3.8` version. Also why aren't you using the Spring Boot managed hibernate version. If you want a different version provide `<hibernate.version>version-here</hibernate.version>` in the `<properties>` section of your pom. Work with the framework not around/against it. Also use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead of your own dependencies (you are using an old version of Spring Security which is pulling in an old Spring dependency as well).

Answer (score 2):

Basically your dependencies are a mess.

1. Your are mixing Spring Boot 1.5.0 and 1.3.8 release jars, never mix versions of a framework
2. You are including an old version of Spring Security pulling in an old, unsupported, Spring version
3. If you want to use a specific version of Hibernate just specify the version, don't include them yourself.

Your dependencies should look something like this.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>      
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>b7</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Notice the addition of the `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-validation` and `spring-boot-starter-mail` to get the proper dependencies.

To pin the hibernate version add this

```
<properties>
 <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Hi , while removing the version , i got the error "'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:jar is missing. @ line 100, column 15", so i guess atleast that is needed as when i added it , it got removed ...

Comment: Ah you are using Spring Boot 1.5, that doesn't support log4j anymore only log4j2 and logback are supported. Switch your logging framework.

Comment: Changed to 
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
      
  </dependency>
Still the error

Comment: What error? That shouldn't happen if your parent is correct.

Comment: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider: method <init>()V not found"

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider: method <init>()V not found
```

refers to the no-args constructor of class ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider being not found.

This constructor exist since version 4.3.6 of Spring 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html#ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider--

```
protected ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider()
Protected constructor for flexible subclass initialization.
Since:
4.3.6
```

Make sure your spring-context is running version at least 4.3.6

**Edit:** you can try to run the following on your project to identify which versions of your dependencies maven is resolving.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: I have turned it into 4.3.10 still no use , also i have updated the pom to<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: could you send the output of the mvn dependency:tree ?
I cannot try locally I don't have access to maven repo right now

Comment: Added dependency tree

Comment: I just tried with spring-boot 1.5.5 and spring-context 4.3.10 and it works fine

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.5.RELEASE)
Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

You are manually setting versions of the Spring Framework, and other dependencies. You should not do this.

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

```
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Additionally a lot of the other dependencies you are defining you should let be pulled transitively from the Spring Boot Starters else you risk the same runtime issues where there are incompatible versions of the dependencies.

Comment: I have made changes to my pom.xml but i am still getting the error .