# Spring Boot 2 Upgrade not able to resolve class name as property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

We have an application where one of our internal libraries has defined a bean like this

```
<bean id="myBean" class="${myBean.type}"/>
```

We have a Spring Cloud Config Server which feeds properties to this application on startup, which also contains the property `myBean.type`. This setup is currently working fine with no issues. I then made the following change to my pom

**Earlier**

```
<spring.boot.version>1.5.16.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring.cloud.version>
<spring.version>4.3.19.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

**Now**

```
<spring.boot.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>5.0.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring.cloud.version>
```

Then I started getting this error on startup

```
An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.addConstructorArg(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/I:/Library/MavenRepository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.13.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/I:/Library/MavenRepository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.13.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder
```

Looking at this, I excluded the artifact `org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.18:compile` from all the jars that depended on it & upgraded cxf jars versions to `3.2.5`. Now the startup is going ahead but it is giving me the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [${myBean.type}] for bean with name 'myBean' defined in class path resource [xyz.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${myBean.type}
```

I am not sure if removal of `cxf-api` is causing this issue, or upgrade of Spring Boot 2, or is it something else that is going wrong here!

Comment: You will need to make more changes to update to Boot2.  Maybe this is helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730972/no-such-method-error-when-trying-to-run-spring-boot-app

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Most of my code is written in Java Annotations but the libraries are pretty old and multiple teams are using them, so I cannot make a change to the library here. Do you think that is the cause of issue with Spring boot 2?

Comment: It looks like something in your project is using a version of Spring where `BeanDefinitionBuilder` had a method `addConstructorArg`. Version [5.0.13.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.13.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) doesn't have that method. Look for an old version of Spring in your project's dependency tree and try upgrading whatever is pulling that in.

Comment: @Josef7 yes, that was because of the cxf-api jar which I removed. The actual issue now is of bean class not being read from properties.

Comment: It seems likely that something is trying to load the missing class from the cxf-api jar, since it's a required dependency

Comment: @Josef7 in that case why would it have a problem in resolving the property `${myBean.type}` when the corresponding class exists on the classpath.